# permalinks are not working correctly?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I make a site on workpress . now it is live . during study of SEO i change the permalinks now i want to re do my work but its not work 
my old permalinks : http://cart.pakbargain.com/contact-me/
my new permalinks :http://cart.pakbargain.com/?product_cat=women
i have change it from dashboard settings->permalinks from plain to custom but its not work .

Comment: It seems like `.htaccess` was not generated. When you are changing the permalink options `Settings - Permalinks`, does WordPress prompts you about manually creating the `.htaccess` file and paste its contents?

Comment: no i does not give me any prompts

Comment: Check your website root, do you have `.htaccess` file there? If so, post its content to your question.

Comment: ok i will past its content

Comment: what i have to change in my htaccess file ?

Comment: Show us your `.htaccess` file, what do you see there?